# Running tests in Intellij with Jackson

Tags: intellij-idea, jackson

When I run my Controller Tests through Intellij, Lombok throws an error like this:

`fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of com.some.Name`

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Name {
    private final String lastName;
}
```

If I remove finals and add a `@NoArgsConstructor` everything works.

But it's a problem only with tests inside Intellij. The application works perfectly and the tests run pass with gradle.

Am I missing some configuration? :thinking_face:

Comment: As far as I know, Jackson needs a non-argument constructor, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25368565/4934937

Comment: Please provide the test sample that runs ok with Gradle and fails with IDEA. Thanks